# UWP - Angular integration

Tags: javascript, angular, uwp

Recently I have been attempting to integrate Google's Angular 5 build into a JavaScript based Universal Windows Application project in Visual Studio, unfortunately with no that much of success whatsoever. Mostly failing at achieving a working communication between the compiled Angular JavaScript code and JavaScript files where I would like to use UWP namespaces.

My current folder structure looks the following: 
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnCOQ.png)

The front-end displays just fine, although as said previously I have difficulties figuring out how to integrate it with the code responsible for handling the IO operations (located in main.js). I assume it is rather impossible using the already compiled angular project, therefore my question - how do I do it from within the angular components?

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but how did you integrate Angular in a UWP project? I can't get it done.

Comment: You should develop your angular app separately using the global winjs namespace from within your components in order to access UWP specific apis (see the accepted answer). Once ready with your app you just build it using --prod flag and put the dist files into the tree of your uwp project and import .js files to your main html using appropriate paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused with the "compiled Angular" part, but if you have an Angular app inside the UWP project, most of the UWP API is accessible through the `Windows` namespace, something from `WinJS`, so inside an Angular Service/Component you can create a function such as this:

```
windowsFileSavePicker(source, successCB, errorCB) {
    var savePicker = Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
    //savePicker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.downloads;
    savePicker.fileTypeChoices.insert(source.mimeType, [source.fileName.replace(/^.*([.][^.]*)$/, '$1')]);
    savePicker.suggestedFileName = source.fileName;

    savePickerHandler = fileSavePickerHandler.bind(undefined, source, successCB, errorCB);

    if (platform.isWindowsPhone()) { // Win 8.1
        Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("activated", savePickerHandler);
        savePicker.pickSaveFileAndContinue();
    }
    else // UWP
        savePicker.pickSaveFileAsync().then(savePickerHandler);
}
```

In several Cordova apps I used snippets like this (e.g. from inside the Angular's `main.js`):

```
if (window.WinJS && window.WinJS.Application) {
    window.WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function () {
        backButtonBehavior();
        return true; // return true to prevent app closing
    };
}
```

Which could be beneficial for testing the Angular part of the app in a browser (or wherever you don't have the UWP API).

I've never had the need to "communicate" from inside the Angular app to the outside UWP parts of the application (as I was doing everything inside the Angular app), but you can create an interface or a "carriage" object in the UWP part, attach it to the global namespace (`window`; or perhaps there is an UWP api for this?) and then access it from inside the Angular app through the global namespace.